# AWS VPN with split tunnel cannot connect to Internet after connecting to AWS VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, aws-ec2

AWS VPN with split tunnel enabled. When I connect to the VPN with the AWS VPN Client, I lose Internet on my Mac endpoint. However, I do seem to reach the VPN as I see my connection in the AWS VPN console.

- I have a VPC with IPv4 CIDR 172.31.0.0/16 and 3 subnets 172.31.32.0/20, 172.31.0.0/20 and 172.31.16.0/20
- The VPC has an internet gateway attached.
- I have a Client VPN endpoints with Client CIDR 10.0.0.0/22 and it has one of the subnets associated as "Target network associations". The one with 172.31.0.0/20.
- The endpoint has a security group which does have a Outbound rules to allow all traffic.
- The endpoint has a "Authorization rules" to allow all the VPC and Destination CIDR 172.31.0.0/16.
- The endpoint has a "Route table" to allow all traffic for the selected subnet (172.31.0.0/20)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the issue. I was following [this tutorial](https://plainenglish.io/blog/how-to-setup-aws-client-vpn-ef87b80262b4) but that missed the last steps (5 to 8) of the step 5 from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-getting-started.html#cvpn-getting-started-routes). I was able to detect this by reading the step 8 of this other [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/scenario-internet.html).